# Oracle SQL optional primary key

Tags: sql, oracle, reference, primary-key, option-type

I'm having a problem in an oracle SQL project I'm working on:

I have a (weak) entity 'Ticket' that has as primary key: (Customer_id,packet_id,project_id,ticket_id). Customer_id, packet_id and project_id are also foreign keys.

But, a ticket can only be for a packet OR a project, and because they are both in the primary key, they can't be null, while one of them actually will always be null. But I need both because a ticket always belongs to a one of them.

I thought of a possible solution and I thought I could make 1 ID for all products, but then there is another problem, because if I want to implement this product_id as a foreign key, I don't know to which entity I should let it reference to.

Is there a way to make 'optional primary keys' or work with if-statements when creating tables? Or a way to make an optional reference? I've tried if-statements and a case but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot will depend on exactly what these entities represent.  Since a ticket can be for either a packet or a project, that implies that there is some higher-level entity that combines both packets and projects.  That could either be modeled as a new table that is the parent to both `PACKET` and `PROJECT` or it could be modeled by combining the `PACKET` and `PROJECT` table and adding a `TYPE` column that differentiates between packets and projects.  The `TICKET` table would then reference either the new parent table or the combined table.

Taking a step back, though, if the `TICKET` entity has a `TICKET_ID`, it seems likely that the `TICKET_ID` alone should be the primary key.  It seems unusual that you would have a composite primary key if you have a `TICKET_ID` column-- do you really want to allow multiple rows in the `TICKET` table with the same `TICKET_ID` that are related to different customers, packets, and projects?  If `TICKET_ID` alone is the primary key, then both `PACKET_ID` and `PROJECT_ID` can be nullable foreign keys and you can create a `CHECK` constraint that ensures that exactly one of the two is non-NULL.